# Monotone convergence theorem for operators in the weak operator topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

For real numbers, we know that any monotonic bounded sequence converges to a finite limit. Does this generalize to sequences of operators?

More formally, I have a sequence of operators $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where each $A_n: \ell_1 \to \ell_1$ and $\|A_n\|_1 \leq 1$. I know from the Banach-Alaoglu theorem that the unit ball $\{T : \ell_1 \to \ell_1 $ such that $ \|T\|_1 \leq 1\}$ is compact when the space of operators is endowed with the weak operator topology.

By weak operator topology I mean that $\{A_n\}$  converges to $A$ if and only if for all $x \in \ell_1^*$ and $y \in \ell_1$ we $$ \langle x ,A_n y \rangle \to \langle x, A y \rangle .$$

Does the Banach-Alaoglu theorem imply that if we have a monotonicity property
$A_1 \leq A_2 \leq A_3 \leq ...$ that the sequence converges (in the weak topology) to some operator $A : \ell_1 \to \ell_1$?

Comment: From your second paragraph you must mean by "weak topology" the topology of pointwise convergence in the weak topology on $\ell_1$ rather than the Banach space weak topology.  But even with that interpretation it is clear that the answer is no. Take the projection $P_n$  onto the first $n$ unit vectors of $\ell_1$.  The sequence $(P_N)$  converges in the pointwise weak$^*$ topology to the identity operator, but not pointwise in the weak operator topology.  This is basically obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a clarification of what I mean by the weak operator topology. With this convergence definition, the sequence of projections $P_n$ will converge to the identity map.

Comment: What does $\le$ mean here?

Comment: @NateEldredge  That's a good question. All the elements in the sequences I am interested in can be expressed as infinite-dimensional matrices. $A \leq B$ means that the $A_{ij} \leq B_{ij}$ for all $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}^2$. But I'm not sure this is a true partial order on the set of operators on $\ell^1$. Maybe a better way of defining it is that for all $x \in \ell_1,y \in \ell_1^*$ with positive coordinates, we have $$y A x \leq y B x$$

Comment: So, is that equivalent to saying that $B-A$ is positivity preserving?

Comment: Then don't we conclude that for every nonnegative $x$, the sequence $A_n x$ is pointwise increasing and $\ell^1$ bounded.  So monotone convergence says it converges in $\ell^1$ to some $y$.  By considering positive and negative parts, we get the same without the nonnegativity assumption.  So this would seem to imply that $A_n$ converges in the strong operator topology.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment. I agree from your comment that, for a fixed x, the sequence $\{A_n x\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ will converge to some value $y(x)$. Furthermore, we will have $y(x+x') = y(x) + y(x')$ and $y(cx) = cy(x)$ so $y$ is a linear operator on $\ell_1$. 

However, this seems like convergence in the weak topology (not strong) to me. For example---as  Bill Johnson suggested---suppose that $A_n$ is the projection $P_n$ on the first $n$ coordinates. Then $A_n x$ is pointwise increasing and $\ell_1$ bounded. However, $\|A_n - A_m\|_1 = 1$ so the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: I said [**strong operator topology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology), not the operator norm topology.  And I wish you would stop saying "weak topology" when you mean "weak operator topology".  They are not the same and the definitions are crucial here.  Note the limiting operator $y$ will be a bounded operator by the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Apologies for the confusion, I haven't worked with these concepts before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've clarified in comments that $\le$ means that the operators $A_{n+1} - A_n$ are positivity preserving.  So for any nonnegative $x \in \ell^1$, we have $A_1 x \le A_2 x \le \dots$ pointwise.  Since $A_1 x \in \ell^1$ and the sequence $\{A_n x\}$ is $\ell^1$-bounded, the monotone convergence theorem implies that $A_n x$ converges in $\ell^1$-norm to some $Ax \in \ell^1$.  For general $x \in \ell^1$, writing $x = x^+ - x^-$ shows that again $A_n x$ converges in $\ell^1$-norm to some $Ax$.  In particular, $\|A_n x\|_1 \to \|Ax\|_1$ which implies that $A$ is bounded with operator norm at most 1.  We have thus shown $A_n \to A$ in the strong operator topology, which is even more than requested.